# Prevent GPS draining battery of cell phone when location is searched

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I'm using LocationManager's method `requestLocationUpdates` to get the location of the cell phone.

I'm using GPS as the Provider and working with a `LocationListener` to update the UI of my app.

I need to call a method on my Activity every 1000 milliseconds. To do that, I configured the `requestLocationUpdates` like this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 1000, listener);
```

Everything is working well. The `onLocationChanged` method is called and the Latitude and Logitude are showed ok.

But I have some doubts.

1. What happens if I'm in a place with no GPS signal?.
2. There is some `automatic` Timeout?
3. Or the App will try to get the position using the GPS all the time and will drain the battery.
4. What happens if I switch to `WiFI/3G` Provider and thats signals also aren't working? It happens the same?

I search over Internet looking for the answer but I can't find the right solution.

Comment: 1. If you have no GPS and no provider signal you won't be able to get a location. 2. Not that I know of, it will run til you or the server stops it (the server will stop it once you hit the maximum requests). 3. Yes, making regular requests (especially every 1000ms even though it won't really pull them that fast) will kill your battery. 4. If you switch to your provider and they aren't working as well you won't get updates. You have to have some sort of connection to pull location updates.

Comment: So using GPS or WiFi/3G, not having signal, If I don't make a way to stop the "pulling" the battery will be drain?. There is some right way to do that?? Thanks

Comment: If you don't have a signal it will simply keep looking for one, which would eventually drain your battery. You could setup some sort of timer that will stop your service once you haven't gotten a signal for a certain period of time and prompt the user to try again when there is a signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example let's say you are driving in a car and the LocationManager is connected to a valid GPS provider. Now you driving through a tunnel and lose the signal. Now `onLocationChanged()` isn't triggered anymore. But the system will keep searching in background for a valid GPS provider. If you are through the tunnel the system reconnects to the GPS provider, if still available, and `onLocationChanged()` is triggered again.

The drain of the battery while connected and getting location updates is much higher as when the system is looking for a valid provider.

If you switch to WiFi or 3G the system will look for the last set provider and overrides the previous one. But the behaviour will be the same.

You can react on this event by monitoring the `LocationListener.onStatusChanged()` callback and the [GpsStatus.Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html) interface. E.g. switch to another provider or if no provider is available call `removeLocationUpdates()` and call `requestLocationUpdates()` again after a period of time with a `Timer`. This will save your battery much better.

Edit:

`LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` returns true if GPS is enabled in the settings of the device. It's no indicator that you are connected to a GPS provider. 
Use the method [LocationManager.getBestProvider(Criteria, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29) to know which provider is available.

As a note: You will almost never get a connection to GPS if you are inside of a room.

Comment: I'm testing this situation. I'm inside my house (there is no GPS signal inside). I run my app. The app check for GPS using locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); and return true. But, when the method locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 1000, listener); is called, start trying to get the signal and nothing happens. None of the LocationListener method is called. Not onLocationChanged, not onStatusChanged, nothing. In this case, the battery is drained and I don't know what to do

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you are telling me that I'm right. THE problem is that it doesn't exist any way to truncate GPS pulling?. There is not way to add a Timeout?, a right and simple way to do?

Comment: Yes, only removeLocationUpdates(...) will stop this mechanism.